# What's the best method to parse strings for multiple word combinations?

Tags: java, string, parsing

I'm writing a program that attempts to derive meaning from natural language. The program will accept a String, and see if it contains certain combinations of words. See the following code snippet for an example:

```
if (phrase.contains("turn")) { // turn something on/off
    if (phrase.contains("on") && !phrase.contains("off")) { // turn something ON
        if (phrase.contains("pc") || phrase.contains("computer")) // turn on computer
            turnOnComputer();
        else if (phrase.contains("light") || phrase.contains("lamp")) // turn on lights
            turnOnLights();
        else
            badPhrase();
    }
    else if (phrase.contains("off") && !phrase.contains("on")) { // turn something OFF
        if (phrase.contains("pc") || phrase.contains("computer")) // turn off computer
            turnOffComputer();
        else if (phrase.contains("light") || phrase.contains("lamp")) // turn off lights
            turnOffLights();
        else
            badPhrase();
    }
    else {
        badPhrase();
    }
}
else {
    badPhrase();
}
```

As you can see, this can quickly become an unmanageable mess of code if I want to interpret more than a few meanings. How can I manage this better?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thanks for pointing that out. It shouldn't, but I didn't want to spend time fixing that with more if-statements.

Comment: It won't. Sorry, that was my mistake.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Well, it certainly has similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure how applicable your approach is to natural language processing. Also, aren't there already existing libraries for NLP? In particular, in NLP, I know that sometimes order and part of speech matter a lot, plus this approach is not very robust for word variations.

However, if you want to stick with your approach, one idea to make it more readable and more maintainable (see fuller pros/cons below) is something like this:

```
StringFinder finder = new StringFinder(phrase);
if        (finder.containsAll("turn", "on").andOneOf("computer", "pc").andNot("off").matches()) {
    turnOnComputer();
    return;
} else if (finder.containsAll("turn", "off").andOneOf("computer", "pc").andNot("on").matches()) {
    turnOffComputer();
    return;
} else if (finder.containsAll("turn", "on").andOneOf("light", "lamp").andNot("off").matches()) {
    ...
} else if (finder.containsAll("turn")) { // If we reached this point
    badPhrase();
} else if (...
```

With something like:

```
class StringFinder {
    private final String phrase;
    private final Map<String, Boolean> cache = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

    public StringFinder(String phrase) { this.phrase = phrase; }

    public StringFinder containsAll(String... strings) {
        for (String string : strings) {
            if (contains(string) == false) return new FailedStringFinder(phrase);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public StringFinder andOneOf(String... strings) {
        for (String string: strings) {
            if (contains(string)) return this;
        }
        return FailedStringFinder(phrase);
    }

    public StringFinder andNot(String... strings) {
        for (String string : strings) {
            if (contains(string)) return new FailedStringFinder(phrase);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public boolean matches() { return true; }

    private boolean contains(String s) {
        Boolean cached = cache.get(s);
        if (cached == null) {
            cached = phrase.contains(s);
            cached.put(s, cached);
        }
        return cached;
    }


}

class FailedStringFinder extends StringFinder {
    public boolean matches() { return false; }

    // The below are actually optional, but save on performance:
    public StringFinder containsAll(String... strings) { return this; }
    public StringFinder andOneOf(String... strings) { return this; }
    public StringFinder andNot(String... strings) { return this; }
}
```

Disadvantages:

- Duplication of checks: "turn" is checked multiple times.
- Repeated patterns (but see advantages below).

Advantages:

- Relatively terse code.
- Checks are duplicated but cached, so that performance remains high.
- The condition is very close to the operation, resulting in a very readable code.
- Not nesting conditions allows for changing the condition required for a specific operation without restructuring the code, leading to a lot more maintainable code.
- Easy to change the order in which conditions and operations appear, to control priorities.
- The lack of nesting makes it easier to parallelize it in the future.
- Flexible condition checking: for example you can add methods to StringFinder to match with repeated checks, such as: `public StringFinder containsOnAndNotOff() { return containsAll("on").andNot("off"); }`, or to match some exotic conditions that you need, such as `andAtLeast3Of(String... strings) {...}`.

  - The cache could also be extended to not only remember whether words appear, but to remember whether whole patterns appear.
  - You could also add the ultimate condition: `andMatches(Pattern p)` (with a Regex pattern) - in fact, you can probably model many other checks with a regex. Then it would make it easy to cache - instead of using a string as a key, use a pattern.

Comment: Wow, thank you! This is much easier to read, and easy to edit.

Comment: FYI: Your code had a few errors, so I have posted an answer containing the corrected code. This will remain my accepted answer.

Comment: @BLuFeNiX that's what you get when writing code in a text editor :) thanks for the corrections!

Answer (score 3):

**[Apache OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/)** is a machine learning based toolkit for the processing of natural language text.

It includes a *sentence detector*, a *tokenizer*, a *parts-of-speech (POS) tagger*, and a *treebank parser*.

[Manual for NLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html)

[Download](http://opennlp.apache.org/cgi-bin/download.cgi)

Hope it helps ; )

Answer (score 2):

Keyword spotting is certainly only manageble for a very small set of words and/or a very restricted input language. Ok, maybe also if surrounding text doesn't matter.

However for that kind of natural language parsing you need a more complex approach like tokenizing the text first and then try to find syntactic relations between words (start with direct neighbours and extend the range later). Finally use the syntactic relations you found as control codes to drive your action decisions.

Regular expressions are likely not the answer here as they require a very strict input. Consider a sentence like this:

> Don't turn the light off, but turn it on.

Neither RE nor your original approach will give you any sensible result. Also, don't forget syntactic or grammatical errors.

Comment: I would love to be able to support sentences like this, but it seems like a lofty goal. I wouldn't know where to start. Your explanation makes sense, but actually implementing it seems like a nightmare.

Comment: My example is for a pure natural language. It makes the task a lot easier if you can limit the input language (e.g. allow only a certain set of keywords and modifiers). But even then you are faced with all kinds of free text you have to make sense of. Maybe a simple programming language (domain specific language) would be enough? This could then be handled by a normal parser instead, which would make your task a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex to achieve what you want as regex can match for a combination of strings.

Comment: After some Googling, I think I want something like this: `if (phrase.matches("^(?=.*?(light|lamp))(?=.*?(turn))(?=.*?(on))((?!off).)*$")) { turnOnLights(); }`

Is there a way to simplify this syntax?

Comment: If you have complex logic then regex will be complex. I am not a regex expert so cannot suggest if this regex can be made simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fixed code from the answer supplied by @Oak

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class StringFinder {
    private final String phrase;
    private final Map<String, Boolean> cache = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

    public StringFinder(String phrase) { this.phrase = phrase; }

    public StringFinder containsAll(String... strings) {
        for (String string : strings) {
            if (contains(string) == false) return new FailedStringFinder(phrase);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public StringFinder andOneOf(String... strings) {
        for (String string: strings) {
            if (contains(string)) return this;
        }
        return new FailedStringFinder(phrase);
    }

    public StringFinder andNot(String... strings) {
        for (String string : strings) {
            if (contains(string)) return new FailedStringFinder(phrase);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public boolean matches() { return true; }

    private boolean contains(String s) {
        Boolean cached = cache.get(s);
        if (cached == null) {
            cached = phrase.contains(s);
            cache.put(s, cached);
        }
        return cached;
    }


}

class FailedStringFinder extends StringFinder {

    public FailedStringFinder(String phrase) {
        super(phrase);
    }

    public boolean matches() { return false; }

    // The below are actually optional, but save on performance:
    public StringFinder containsAll(String... strings) { return this; }
    public StringFinder andOneOf(String... strings) { return this; }
    public StringFinder andNot(String... strings) { return this; }
}
```